# python the list in dict extend value

Tags: python, list

How do I create a dictionary of lists? Here is what I tried:

```py
zigzag = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 4),[])
for i in range(1, 4):
    zigzag[i].extend(range(i, 13 , 4))
```

What I expected to get was:

```py
{
  1: [1,5,9,13],
  2: [2,6,10],
  3: [3,7,11]
}
```

But the actual result had the same list in each value:

```py
{
  1: [1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11],
  2: [1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11],
  3: [1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11]
}
```

I don't know how that result happened. How can I get my expected answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys):

> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value* defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance, **so it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object such as an empty list**. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

In Python, assignments of mutable objects like a list do not create a new object: they just make a new reference to the existing object. So what you are seeing is that each value in the dictionary is actually referencing the same empty list that you passed into `dict.fromkeys()`.

Instead you could simply do

```py
zigzag = {}
for i in range(1, 4):
    zigzag[i] = list(range(i, 14 , 4))
```

Or using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) like the documentation recommmends:

```py
zigzag = { i: list(range(i, 14, 4)) for i in range(1,4) }
```

Further reading on mutable vs immutable data types in Python:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a

#### Note on `range()`

Also, if you are expecting `13` to be present in `zigzag[1]`, then you should use a stop value of `14`, not `13`. The stop value is exclusive. From the docs on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

> For a positive *step*, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.